# SARIMA: simulation within limits

Tags: arima, regression-coefficients, simulation

I am trying to generate hypothetical data through the SARIMA random process. I implement this via statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.simulate where I manually define the coefficients. Here is the an example snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX as SARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_simulations = 156

params = [0.0, 0.278, 0.252, 0.254, 0.154, 0.4, 0.003]  
order = [2, 1, 2]
seasonal_order = [1, 0, 0, 52] 

empty_dataset = np.zeros(100+n_simulations)
model = SARIMA(
  empty_dataset, 
  order=order, 
  seasonal_order=seasonal_order,
  trend='c', 
  enforce_stationary=True,
  enforce_invertibility=True,
  use_exact_diffuse=True
)
simulations = model.simulate(params, 1500+ts_length)[100:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].plot(simulations)
ax[1].plot(np.exp(simulations))
```

My question is: How can I generate data that falls in a specific range e.g. [0, 200]? How can I control the output of simulations via coefficients?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the errors (shocks, innovations) are random and have an **unbounded support** such as $\varepsilon\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, you cannot ensure the data $x$ following a SARIMA model will fall in a specific interval; there could always be a shock sufficiently large so that the corresponding value of the series falls outside any set interval such as $[0,200]$.

If the error distribution has a **bounded support** that is sufficiently tight, e.g. $\varepsilon\sim\text{Uniform}[-1,1]$, the starting value is (well) inside the interval of interest (e.g. in its centre) and the length of the simulated series is sufficiently short, you can ensure the data $x$ will fall in a specific range. The intuition here is that the process cannot wander too far off the starting point well inside the interval if both the steps are small (due to the bounded error distribution) and the number of steps taken is small.

In any case, you can always **normalize*** the simulated series to fit into a desired interval. To fit into $[0, 200]$, you would subtract the minimum value from the series, divide by the range and multiply by $200$:
$$
\tilde{x}=\frac{x-\min(x)}{\text{range}(x)}\times 200.
$$
The values of the normalized series $\tilde{x}$ will lie inside $[0,200]$.

*The term *normalize* may typically be used for squeezing the data into the interval $[0,1]$, but the idea is very much the same regardless of what specific interval it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.